# Sequential Containers || C++ Primer Fifth Edition Exercise 9.22

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, sequential

I am baffled by this exercise.

> Exercise 9.22: Assuming iv is a vector of ints, what is wrong with the following program? How might you correct the problem(s)?

```
vector<int>::iterator iter = iv.begin(),
                      mid  = iv.begin() + iv.size()/2;

while(iter != mid)     
    if(*iter == some_val)
        iv.insert(iter, 2 * some_val)
```

The first thing I would do is go and ask what the intent of this program was. Since I am not sure who wrote this section of the book and don't want to bother the authors for something probably trivial I started guessing.

I assume they want to insert the double of the first value in the vector until the value is in the middle. (since they point iter to the beginning and never move through the vector to look for an actual value (then again they named it some_val, to look for a value not at the beginning is a trivial fix, but then one would have to validate that the value actually is in the first half of the container))

so a) vector would grow like this?

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
{(2),1,2,3,4,5}
{2,(2),1,2,3,4,5}
{2,2,(2),1,2,3,4,5}
```

The first problem in that case, inserting in a vector most likely instantly invalidates the iterators.
We could use a list instead, but then we can't use iterator arithmetic to calculate the mid.
Calculating the mid only once like in the example is not enough, since in a list like a.) it would point to the 3 and keep pointing to the 3, just because we called the iterator mid and initialized him with the element in the mid doesn't mean it still points to the mid after all those inserts.

So here is what I did:

```
vector<int>::iterator iter=iv.begin();

while(iter!=iv.begin()+iv.size()/2){    //calculating mid each time
    if(*iter==some_val)
        iv.insert(iter,2*some_val);

    iter=iv.begin();                        //revalidate iter
    while(*iter!=some_val)                  //find the original first element
        ++iter;
}
```

I see how the exercise forces you to think about which sequential container to use and how iterators behave in a growing container, but the way the exercise is presented, still baffles me. Did I miss some obvious point?

PS: Since the whole chapter deals with sequential containers I did not focus on the problems that arise with the condition in the while loop (it is like they forgot everything they taught just a few chapters ago).

Comment: I think the whole point of the exercise is just the invalidation of iterators. And you might want to see what [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) returns.

Comment: First thing I noticed is `iv.instert`. Its probably not the wanted problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through the program step by step, and update the code style to modern C++:

```
auto iter = iv.begin(); // type will be std::vector<int>::iterator
const auto mid  = iv.begin() + iv.size()/2; // type will be std::vector<int>::iterator

while(iter != mid)
{
  if(*iter == some_val)
    iv.insert(iter, 2 * some_val);
}
```

The first two lines create your iterator pair.
The loop iterates until you reach the middle of your vector.
The condition inside the loop checks that the value at the position `iter` is pointing to is equal to some predefined value `someval`.
The next line of code inserts a new item into the vector, equal to double the value of `some_val`.

Now to answer your questions: the insert line does indeed invalidate all iterators, and that is indeed the problem in the program. Additionally, the iterator doesn't iterate, as it is never incremented.
One invalidation can be solved by using the return value of the `insert` call to make `iter` valid and usable again:

```
iter = iv.insert(iter, 2*some_val);
```

But this still leaves us with `mid`. There is not enough info in your question to fix this bit, but possible options are:

```
while(std::distance(iter, iv.end()) > iv.size()) // shift the middle when the vector grows

const auto half = iv.size()/2;
while(std::distance(iter, iv.begin()) < half) // only iterate until iter is halfway the original length by insertion
```

So an example solution might look like this:

```
auto iter = iv.begin();

while(std::distance(iter, iv.begin()) < iv.size()/2) // iterate until halfway the current vector
{
  if(*iter == some_val)
    iter = iv.insert(iter, 2 * some_val);
  else
    ++iter;
}
```

But this might of course not be the intended solution.

Comment: Also, very helpful, thanks! I am glad I am not the only one who thinks this question lacks info.

Comment: @JWD Well, the question itself may be intentionally unclear to spark the inner workings of your brain or incite a discussion in a classroom. Just put it under: "creatively thinking about code" `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

The original code doesn't advance and invalidates all used iterators.

```
 vector<int>::iterator iter = iv.begin(),
                          mid  = iv.begin() + iv.size()/2;

 while(iter != mid)
         if(*iter == some_val)
                  iv.instert(iter, 2 * some_val);
```

There are more problems

```
vector<int>::iterator iter = iv.begin(),
                      mid  = iv.begin() + iv.size()/2;
int s = iv.size()/2; // assuming we should stop at the original position

while(iter != iv.begin() + s) { // update end condition if that is the intended function
     if(*iter == some_val) {
              iter = iv.instert(iter, 2 * some_val); // gets new valid iter
              ++s; // update position of mid 
              ++iter; // skips the inserted
     }
     ++iter; // advance in vector.
}
```

Comment: ++iter and ++s make (iter != iv.begin() + s) a condition that never becomes true if (*iter == some_val). I still like your answer because it made the possible intend of the exercise the clearest to me!

Comment: @JWD, you are right, I need to skip the inserted and then advance, but that is only one possible interpretation of the intent of the Exercise.